# waagent not deprovisioning on preparing debian VHD Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When running the final command which is `sudo waagent –force -deprovision` after preparing a Debian VHD for Kali but it keeps finishing with the below messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 33, in <module>
sys.exit(load_entry_point('WALinuxAgent==2.2.47', 'console_scripts', 'waagent')())
File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
return next(matches).load()
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
module = import_module(match.group('module'))
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib.bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib.bootstrap>", line 228, in call_with_frames_removed
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azurelinuxagent/agent.py", line 34, in <module>
import azurelinuxagent.common.event as event
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azurelinuxagent/common/event.py", line 632, in <module>
event_logger = EventLogger()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azurelinuxagent/common/event.py", line 304, in init
osutil = get_osutil()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azurelinuxagent/common/osutil/factory.py", line 50, in get_osutil
return _get_osutil(distro_name, distro_code_name, distro_version, distro_full_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azurelinuxagent/common/osutil/factory.py", line 79, in _get_osutil
return DebianOSBaseUtil()
NameError: name 'DebianOSBaseUtil' is not defined`
```

The deployment fails in Azure and I think this may be apart of that issue. I have reviewed their documentation and seen users having the same issue. Anyone ever faced this issue?

The original document in question that was used is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/debian-create-upload-vhd

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an error in the factory.py file.

try changing line 25 to add ", DebianOSBaseUtil" to the end of the import statement.